# Jquery autocomplete / combobox + external source?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, combobox

Im looking for an selectbox autocompleter that does exactly what combobox does, if a value don't exist return false / null.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Is there a way to use an external datasource with combobox? Or anyone can recommend me a good selectbox script that will do that?

Thanks,

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the UI combobox widget, I use the jQuery plug-in called Combobox. It only allows selections from the select tag's options, which I think is your first requirement above. I don't recall if can populate the options from external data. Check the documentation.  I'm pretty sure that some of the combobox plug-ins will populate from external data.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery remote combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) does allow you to use remote data.